# JPA criteria perform count on left outer join

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am new to JPA criteria. Now I want to create the particular criteria for my DB2 query but no luck. Below is the DB2 query that I wish to create by using JPA criteria:

```
SELECT 
    p.payeeId, 
    p.payeeName, 
    COUNT(s.id) AS noOfSetup 
FROM 
    PAYEE p 
LEFT JOIN 
    SETUP s
on 
    p.payeeId = s.payeeId 
GROUP BY
    p.payeeId,
    p.payeeName
```

Below is the JPA criteria that I tried:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Payee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Payee.class);
Join<Payee, Setup> join = root.join(Payee_.setups, JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(
        root.get(Payee_.payeeId),
        root.get(Payee_.payeeName),
        builder.count(join.get(Setup_.id))
        );
criteriaQuery.groupBy(
        root.get(Payee_.payeeId),
        root.get(Payee_.payeeName)
        );
TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Tuple> entities = query.getResultList();
```

Here is the log from JPA

```
select
    payee0_.payeeId as col_0_0_,
    payee0_.payeeName as col_1_0_,
    count(setup1_.id) as col_2_0_ -- <----- this should refer setup2_ but not setup1_
from 
    PAYEE payee0_ 
left outer join 
    SETUP setup2_ 
on 
    payee0_.payeeId=setup2_.payeeId 
cross join 
    SETUP setup1_  -- <----------------- the extra stuff, why?
group by 
    payee0_.payeeId,
    payee0_.payeeName
```

Which is quite different to what I expected. How can I create the JPA criteria as the DB2 query?

Edit 1:

Change to `Join<Payee, Setup> join = root.join("setups", JoinType.LEFT);`

```
select
    payee0_.payeeId as col_0_0_,
    payee0_.payeeName as col_1_0_,
    count(setup2_.id) as col_2_0_ -- <----- now, it refer to the correct setup2_
from 
    PAYEE payee0_ 
left outer join 
    SETUP setup2_ 
on 
    payee0_.payeeId=setup2_.payeeId 
cross join 
    SETUP setup1_  -- <----------------- still here
group by 
    payee0_.payeeId,
    payee0_.payeeName
```

Edit 2:

I apologize for my mistake, especially to @Matthieu Saleta. I didn't show the line of code because I think it doesn't matter. But actually it affect my code. Here is the actual JPA criteria that I create.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Payee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Payee.class);
Root<Setup> root = criteriaQuery.from(Setup.class); // <------ This extra line
Join<Payee, Setup> join = root.join(Payee_.setups, JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(
        root.get(Payee_.payeeId),
        root.get(Payee_.payeeName),
        builder.count(join.get(Setup_.id))
        );
criteriaQuery.groupBy(
        root.get(Payee_.payeeId),
        root.get(Payee_.payeeName)
        );
TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Tuple> entities = query.getResultList();
```

Just remove it will solve the issue.

Comment: What is `Payee_` ? You're querying from table `Payee ccpayee00` and selecting `payee0_` field. It's weird

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta, Payee_ is the [metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/metamodel.html) for Payee. Thank for notice, the ccpayee0_ is typo mistake, it should be payee0_

Comment: Can you try `Join<Payee, Setup> join = root.join("setups", JoinType.LEFT);` ?

Comment: Your Criteria code looks correct to me; "join" is the equivalent of the JPQL "s", so indeed the JPA provider should not have a cross join in there!!

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta, please ignore the reply just now. I try your suggestion, it seem getting near to answer (Refer Edit 1), it refer to the correct `setup2_`, but the `cross join` still there.

Comment: Now, can you try `Join<Payee, Setup> join = root.joinCollection("setups")`, please ?

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta, thank for helping, I solved the issue. This is cause by my own mistake. (See Edit 2)